# QEMU Guest hat not initialized the display (yet) | Ubuntu 21.10 arm64

Tags: server, graphics, virtualization, qemu

Actually I have a problem by using qemu on my Windows 10 to built an Ubuntu arm64 Image.
I creating the qemu VM with packer, it works fine, but it still hang after typing the boot parameters.

After starting my Packer, I getting Popup qemu Display with following error:

```
-> Guest has not initialied the display (yet) <-
```

I trying some Quemu arguments for Display setting, but it still not work
hopefully searching for help.

```
My Packer Version : 1.7.8
Ubuntu Version : 21.10 live server arm64 | 20.04 live server arm64 (test both)
qemu version : 6.2
```

My packer Config:

```
source "qemu" "ubuntu-server" {
  boot_command           = ["<esc><wait>", "<esc><wait>", "<enter><wait>", "/install/vmlinuz<wait>", " initrd=/install/initrd.gz", " auto-install/enable=true", " debconf/priority=critical", " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg<wait>", " -- <wait>", "<enter><wait>"]
  http_directory         = "../config/http"
  iso_checksum           = "${UBUNTU_ISO_CHECKSUM}"
  iso_urls               = ["${UBUNTU_ISO_NAME}"]
  output_directory       = "output/live-server"
  shutdown_command       = "sudo shutdown -P now"
  disk_size              = "60000"
  format                 = "qcow2"
  ssh_handshake_attempts = "20"
  ssh_password           = "XXXX"
  ssh_pty                = "true"
  ssh_timeout            = "245m"
  ssh_username           = "XXXXX"
  vm_name                = "${VM_NAME}"
  net_device             = "virtio-net"
  disk_interface         = "virtio"
  boot_wait              = "15s"
  headless               = "false"
  cpus                   = 4
  memory                 = 8192
  qemu_binary            = "qemu-system-arm.exe"
  qemuargs = [
    [ "-machine", "virt" ],
    [ "-device", "virtio-gpu-pci" ],
    [ "-boot", "strict=off" ],
    [ "-cpu", "max" ],
    [ "-m", "8192M" ],    
    [ "-smp", "4" ],
    [ "-device", "qemu-xhci" ],
    [ "-display", "sdl" ],
    [ "-vga", "std" ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: im adding the actually -bios parameger -bios OVMF.fd for qemu from this site
https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2021/04/how-to-boot-uefi-on-qemu.html , too

Comment: Do not add info as a comment edit the question and put the additional info in it. As I read your question it is about doing something on Windows that you might run on Ubuntu later. If so it is off topic here.

Comment: thx david for informatin, i try to change a new UEFI File for initial booting vith packer.

Comment: I'm having same issue with ubuntu server live 20.04 ARM64. Yesterday i successfully booted this, but i want to try to install a full ubuntu instalation in order to get access to some kernel drivers i'm not being able to install: https://shorturl.at/kzLN0
I don't know what packer is, but I have Qemu installed and i tried many things for this to work. for example:
`qemu-system-aarch64 -cpu cortex-a53 -smp 4 -M virt -drive file=hda.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -cdrom ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso -m 4G -boot d`. Similar with X86_64 and propper iso works.

Comment: I've already made it, but the propper answer will be better for a new question.